# How to insert a function from another package in the server.R - Shiny?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, lidar

I'm trying to insert a table on Shiny that is gonna be generated from a rLiDAR function. However, I'm having trouble to figure out how to insert this function in server.R. Here's what I was trying to do:

```
output$summary <- renderTable({    
  table <- summary(Arv.List)    
  Arv.List<-FindTreesCHM(chm, sws, hmin)    
})
```

The function is `FindTreesCHM(chm, sws, hmin)`

Does anyone have a clue of how to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
output$summary <- renderTable({    
  Arv.List <- FindTreesCHM(chm, sws, hmin)    
  summary(Arv.List)    
})
```